Limit of a summation equals integral
I would like to check my answer to a problem. Is my reasoning sound?
The Problem
Suppose $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann Integrable. Prove that
$$\int_a^b f = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n f\left(a + j\cdot\frac{b-a}{n}\right)$$
Note that
$$L(f, [a,b]) = \sup_P L(f, P, [a,b]) = \sup_P\sum_{i = 1}^k(x_i - x_{i - 1})\inf_{[x_{i - 1}, x_i]}f$$
and
$$U(f, [a,b]) = \inf_P U(f, P, [a,b]) = \inf_P\sum_{i = 1}^m(x_i - x_{i - 1})\sup_{[x_{i - 1}, x_i]}f$$
assuming that $m$ and $k$ are the respective lengths of the partitions used.
My Attempt
The right hand side appears to use a Riemann sum where the partition is made of intervals of $n$ equal partitions. In other words, $$x_{j} - x_{j-1} = \frac{b - a}{n}$$
We can then write the right hand side as:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^n (x_{j} - x_{j-1})f\left(a + j\cdot(x_{j} - x_{j-1})\right)$$
Naturally, we should also expect $x_j = a + j\cdot(x_{j} - x_{j-1})$, so the above expression becomes
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^n (x_{j} - x_{j-1})f\left(x_j\right)$$
Now, we observe that for all $j$, $$\inf_{[x_{j-1}, x_j]}f \leq f\left(x_j\right) \leq \sup_{[x_{j-1}, x_j]}f$$
which means
$$L(f, [a,b])\leq\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^n (x_{j} - x_{j-1})f\left(x_j\right) \leq U(f, [a,b])$$
But since $f$ is Riemann, integrable, we should expect
$$L(f, [a,b]) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^n (x_{j} - x_{j-1})f\left(x_j\right) = U(f, [a,b]) = \int_a^bf$$
and we are done.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification

@Mason I have edited the question. Hopefully it is clearer now.

You only get the enclosure for the lower and upper sum of the current partition, not with the limits over all partitions. It is your task to show that the limit $n\to\infty$ with its specific partitions leads to the general limit. Somewhere the idea of "uniformly continuous" should play a role.

@LutzLehmann Why would I need to do that? I thought the inequality $\inf_{[x_{j-1}, x_j]}f \leq f\left(x_j\right) \leq \sup_{[x_{j-1}, x_j]}f$ holds for all partitions $P$.

Yes, up to this point it is correct. But the conclusion after "which means" is wrong, these three quantities can lie any which way. // You are considering a very specific sequence of partitions, you need to show that they actually lead to "a" and then "the" limit. The definition of integrability you use is a rather weak construction in terms of automatically contained properties, so you need to work out the one you need.
